# For which class of graphs can a minimum spanning tree always be associated to a shortest path tree?

Tags: shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree, dijkstras-algorithm

Given a connected graph $G=(X,E)$ with positive edge weights. We assume that $G$ contains a unique min weight spanning tree $T_{\min}$ (this is true for example when for all the cuts, the edge with the minimum weight is unique). What is the necessary and sufficient condition that insures that the following holds:
There exists a vertex $x$ for which the shortest path tree obtained by starting Dijkstra from $x$ coincides with $T_{\min}$.

## Example:

Without the uniqueness assumption, here is an example graph
[image: A graph instance whose MST differs from any SPT]
The following  R code shows that every shortest path tree must use an inner edge that is not part of any MST:

```
x<-c(1,2, 1,8, 2,3, 2,11, 3,4, 4,5, 4,10, 5,6, 6,7, 6,12, 7,8, 8,9,   
   #inner edges that are not part of MST due to their relatively big   weight   
   9,10, 11,12)   
m<-matrix(x,byrow = T, ncol = 2)   
y <- c(2,2,2,1,2,2, 1,2,2,1,2,2,   
     #inner edge weights   
     3.5,3.5)   
arcs <- cbind(m,y)   
#we check only for the three vertices, the others are symetrical to them   
for(i in c(1,2,9)){   
   cat("\n Source:",i,"\n")   
   getShortestPathTree(nodes, arcs, algorithm = "Dijkstra", source.node = i, directed = FALSE)   
}
```

Comment: Since every shortest-path tree can be found by Dijkstra, that property is the same as "$T_{\min}$ is a shortest-path tree for some vertex."

Comment: I must learn how to edit my comments to display source codes.

Comment: I meant, "there exists a vertex  for which the shortest path tree obtained by starting Dijkstra from $x$. coincides with $T_{\min}$" is the same as "$T_{\min}$ is a shortest-path tree for some vertex."

Comment: I think that I was able to prove that with the uniqueness assumption there is always an SPT that coincides with the unique MST. Is this result already known/proven?

Comment: I don't know if we can link this problem to social science: link between selfish behavior (single source SPT) and collective behavior (MST). Then, we need to identify the characteristics of the person (source node for SPT) whose selfishness coicides with the collective goal.

Comment: Consider graph with AB=2, BC=2, CD=2, DA=3, AC=3, BD=3. The unique MST is {AB, BC, CD}. Every SPT will include either AC or BD, an edge that is not in the unique MST.

Comment: @JohnL., I am trying to figure out what is wrong in my proof. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnL. Each edge $e$ not in $MST$ creates a unique cycle $C$. Let $x$ be a vertex of $C$ and let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be the weights of the two chains joining $x$ to $e$. if for at least one $e$ there exists an $x$ for which $l_1$ + $w(e)$ $<$ $l_2$  or $l_2$ + $w(e)$ $<$ $l_1$ then there is no $SPT$ that coincides with the unique $MST$. Am I right? ($x$ can be an endpoint of $e$, in this case  $l_1$ or $l_2$=0)

Comment: I am afraid that this site isn't designed for back-and-forths nor follow-up questions nor interactive discussions. If you need more interactive help, perhaps you can find a friend, tutor, or teaching assistant to help you. It looks like that there is no good answer to the question, "for which class of graphs can a minimum spanning tree always be associated to a shortest path tree?"